# Ubuntu Server cannot connect to wifi

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on a VM in order to get started with Asterisk. The default option on Oracle VM for networking is **NAT** but I needed to change it to **Bridge Networking**. I am using my laptop with a WiFi connection.

When I try to `ping` a site (i.e google) it works perfectly with **NAT**, but not with **Bridge Networking**. I get a message saying: `ping:unknown host www.google.gr`.

I read somewhere (not sure where, but 100% legit), that my wireless card is not supported, but I really doubt this is the case.

I accessed the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and wrote this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 198.162.2.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 198.162.2.1
```

When I accessed the file `/etc/resolv.conf` there was an extra line that said:

```
nameserver 198.162.2.1
```

Can you help me figure out what the problem is? I have tried everything on Virtualbox but I had no chance now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please amend your file to add DNS nameservers:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 198.162.2.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 198.162.2.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. But what was the problem in the first place? Not defining the dns server? Wasn't it enough defining it at `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: It should be declared in `interfaces`. Usually, `resolv.conf` need not be touched.